# Swift Decode and Encode Custom Types

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, codable

I'm having difficulties decoding and encoding one of my classes in Swift.  I have tried following the [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types) documentation but with no luck.

My class layout is as follows:

```
public struct MapLocation: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID public var id: String?
    let originLocation: [MapLandmark]
    let destinationLocation: [MapLandmark]
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case originLocation
        case destinationLocation
    }
}
```

---

```
import Foundation
import MapKit    
struct MapLandmark: Codable {
    let placemark: MKPlacemark
    var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
    var name: String {
        self.placemark.name ?? ""
    }
    var title: String {
        self.placemark.title ?? ""
    }
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D {
        self.placemark.coordinate
    }
}
```

I have tried adding the encoding and decoding classes from the above link but keep running into errors.  What is the best way to implement a solution?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to mention the errors I am getting are:

> "Type 'MapLandmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'"

> "Type 'MapLandmark' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable"

Comment: What is the error you get? `MapLandmark` is not marked as `Codable`. `CLLocationCoordinate2D` is not `Codable`. `MKPlacemark` is definitely not `Codable`.

Comment: When asking for help with errors, **always, always** include the text of the errors. We can't help you fix the problem if we don't know specifically what it is.

Comment: Also, what is the `@DocumentID` propertyWrapper?

Comment: @Sulthan Apologies, the error I am getting is 'Type 'MapLandmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'' and 'Type 'MapLandmark' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable''.  If they're not Codable, is there a work around so I am able to store the MapLandmark structure in Firestore?

Comment: put :Codable after your class name to conform it

Comment: @Caleb Sorry about that, the error I have included the error message in the above comment and will edit my post shortly.

Comment: @gcharita It's Firebase / Firestore

Comment: @sekoya I accidentally missed it out on my submission, but when I add it to the MapLandmark class I get the errors Type 'MapLandmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'' and 'Type 'MapLandmark' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable''.

Comment: MKPlacemark doesn't conform to Codable so you can't use it (directly) in your struct since all properties of a Codable type needs to conform to Codable

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Ok, thank you.  Would the best alternative approach be create a new model and exclude the variable placemark so that I am able to store it in Firestore?

Comment: @user2047296 You can use NSKeyedArchiver to encode it

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks, I'll read into it.  Just to confirm, I should then be able to save that file into firestore?

Comment: @user2047296 You can save any kind of file to FireStore. Check my post below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MKPlacemark` conforms to `NSSecureCoding`. You can just use `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` to encode/decode it. `UUID` already conforms to `Codable`. Try as follow:

```
import MapKit

extension NSSecureCoding {
    func archived() throws -> Data {
        try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: self, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    }
}
```

---

```
extension Data {
    func unarchived<T: NSSecureCoding>() throws -> T? {
        try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(self) as? T
    }
}
```

---

```
struct MapLandmark: Codable {
    let placemark: MKPlacemark
    let id: UUID
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var unkeyedContainer = encoder.unkeyedContainer()
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(placemark.archived())
        try unkeyedContainer.encode(id)
    }
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        var container = try decoder.unkeyedContainer()
        placemark = try container.decode(Data.self).unarchived()!
        id = try container.decode(UUID.self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Leo! That's helped a lot

Comment: Sorry Leo, I have a quick follow up question.  How do I go about using the encode function to encode a MapLandmark object?  Thank you

Comment: Never mind, I realised I was approaching it wrong and used MapLandmark.encode()